# SQL - How to remove from the total what has already been counted

Tags: sql, oracle, cumulative-sum

I'm asking ur help

here this is my set

```
        ID date_answered  
---------- -------------- 
         1 16/09/19       
         2 16/09/19       
         3 16/09/19       
         4 16/09/19       
         5 16/09/19       
         6 16/09/19       
         7 16/09/19       
         8 16/09/19       
         9 16/09/19       
        10 17/09/19       
        11 17/09/19       
        12 17/09/19       
        13 18/09/19       
        14 18/09/19       
        15 18/09/19       
        16 18/09/19       
        17 19/09/19       
        18 19/09/19       
        19 19/09/19       
        20 19/09/19
        21
        22
        23
        24
        25
        26
        27
        28
        29
        30
        31
        32
        33
        34
        35
        36
        37
        38
        39
        40
```

as you can see :

- 16/09/2019 there are 9 people who answered
- 17/09/2019 there are 7 people who answered
- 18/09/2019 there are 4 people who answered
- 19/09/2019 there are 4 people who answered
- there are still 20 people who didnt answer

to calculate how many people answered per day, i have done :

nb_answered =  `count(id) over (partition by date_answered  order by date_answered)`

now my problem is there, i'm trying to get that :

```
date_answered   nb_answered    nb_left  
--------------- -------------- -------- 
16/09/2019           9           40        
17/09/2019           7           31(40-9)  
18/09/2019           4           24(31-7)  
19/09/2019           4           20(24-4)
```

i have tried :

`count(id)  over (order by date_complete rows between  UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)` which give me 40 (total person).

it's cool for the first date, but when i move to the second date i dont know how to have 31.

How can I do that: every day I remove from the total, the number that has already answered

Do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option might be correlated subquery in `SELECT` statement.

Example is a little bit simplified (didn't feel like typing that much).

```
SQL> with test (id, da) as
  2    (select 1, 16092019 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 16092019 from dual union all
  4     select 3, 16092019 from dual union all
  5     select 4, 16092019 from dual union all
  6     select 5, 16092019 from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 6, 17092019 from dual union all
  9     select 7, 17092019 from dual union all
 10     select 8, 17092019 from dual union all
 11     --
 12     select 9, 19092019 from dual union all
 13     --
 14     select 10, null from dual union all
 15     select 11, null from dual union all
 16     select 12, null from dual union all
 17     select 13, null from dual
 18    )
 19  select a.da date_answered,
 20         count(a.id) nb_answered,
 21        (select count(*) from test b
 22         where b.da >= a.da
 23            or b.da is null
 24        ) nb_left
 25  from test a
 26  group by a.da
 27  order by a.da;

DATE_ANSWERED NB_ANSWERED    NB_LEFT
------------- ----------- ----------
     16092019           5         13
     17092019           3          8
     19092019           1          5
                        4          4

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to subtract the overall count from the cumulative count:

```
select date_answered, count(*) as answered_on_date,
       ( count(*) over () -
         sum(count(*)) over (order by date_answered nulls last)
       ) as remaining
from t
group by date_answered
order by date_answered;
```

If you don't want to include the current date, then subtract that as well:

```
select date_answered, count(*) as answered_on_date,
       ( count(*) over () -
         sum(count(*)) over (order by date_answered nulls last) -
         count(*)
       ) as remaining
from t
group by date_answered
order by date_answered;
```

Comment: Thank u Gordon for your answer, but the Littlefoot's solution is what i was looking for :)

Comment: @Jasiek . . . Why?  Does this return the wrong answer?  It is definitely more performant than a subquery.

Comment: I do not understand what is the "remaining" field should give like information. With the LittleFoot's solution i have what i was looking for. I need to calculate the rate between nb_answered and nb_left by day.